# Magento2: get relative path for image

Tags: php, magento2

What I want to do is check in my template file (list.phtml, the product list), if an image exists or not. I can output an existing image like that:

```
<img src="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('Images/imagename.png'); ?>" alt="">
```

My problem is: before showing that I want to check if that image exists. But of course file_exists only takes a relative path and I cannot find out how to get a relative path for my image. Is that possible in magento2 and if so - how?